# Non-trusted users on terminal services

Tags: windows-server-2003, security, windows-terminal-services

We're considering to enable our >10 suppliers (mainly from China) to input/edit/view data via an unified interface. The preferred way is to use the same windows-based .NET/MSSQL application as used internally.

As the application needs a direct database connection, my idea is to grant all suppliers access to a server at our site via terminal services. But there are concerns about the security of this approach, so that the current plan is to develop a web interface to the application (costly) or continue to use excel/txt/word/pdf for data submission (well...).

In *deep* detail, my approach would consist of:

**external server**

Windows Server 2003,  SQL Server 2005, the application

- windows update set on auto
- Terminals Services, granted to individual users
- directly start application (group policy), auto log-off after termination
- adjust file system ACLs to prevent:

  - any file writes (except e.g. profile files)
  - execution of taskmgr, cmd, ftp, telnet, (*explorer.exe?*)
- registry ACLs should be ok
- change RDP port
- firewalled appropriately
- auditing enabled (group policy), report events via e-mail to admins:

  - execution of cmd, taskmgr, etc. (all users, including system/admin/...)
  - change of security permissions

**internal server**

- connected via crossover ethernet
- completely firewalled (inbound)
- synchronize every 5 minutes:

  - open LAN interface
  - synchronize files via network share
  - synchronize database via SQL Server replication (some tables inbound, many outbound)
  - close LAN interface
- backup and history backups (as the external server has the master copy of the applications database)

As I use a similar approach in my department (web- instead of terminal services), I have no objections to the setup. The only practicable attack I'm concerned with, is a breach of in the application itself, which could lead to a compromise of application specific data (over all suppliers).

Nevertheless, as I have to convince a bunch of people favouring the excel approach, I'd like to hear your thoughts.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unfortunate that you're on Server 2003, as Server 2008's RemoteApp features would serve you brilliantly in this scenario. However, what you've got there should pretty much cover it from a security standpoint.

We used to have a TS with un-trusted users on it and the setup was similar. Using GPO we locked down the accounts to remove *everything* - their start menu only had "log off", everything in the Windows Security screen was disabled (except Change Password and Log Off), if they were able to wrangle up a browse screen, access to every local disk was disabled, and they were members of a restricted group that actually had deny access on network resources. Hell we even disabled the ability to right-click on their desktop. We disabled the ability to map client devices over terminal services as well, along with the command prompt, everything.

Basically we went through a GPO and disabled every single feature of the UI we could discover. We did have trouble disabling explorer though, but if you can enforce a single program launch on startup, feel free to disable that too.

A couple of things you may not have thought of:

- I wouldn't bother changing the port. That's just security through obscurity, and it's then a pain in the arse every time you have to read the TS address out to someone
- Enable FIPS compliant encryption on the connection
- If this was Server 2008, I would force Network Level Authentication

Actually, if you can, I would *strongly* suggest moving to 2008 R2 if at all possible, as it's got even more security features for terminal services (or RDS as it's now called)

Comment: Thanks for your hints. RemoteApp seems to be a nice way of delivering the application, although it seems not to be a big security benefit. Using Server 2008 is of course no big deal.

Comment: @Wikser - it can be a security benefit in that it automatically removes a lot of the things you'd have to lock down manually, like the start menu, desktop icons, etc. Yes you still have to lock down a lot of other things, but it's a great kickstart.